# Github single pull request for changes to multiple repositories?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible (or even smart) to pack changes for multiple repositories into a single pull request on Github? Or would it be better to make two separate pull requests?

In my specific case, I am adding a new feature to Paris, the simple Active Record implementation built on top of Idiorm. But the change in Paris also requires a change in Idiorm. Idiorm and Paris are from the same author but live in different repositories.

Can I (and should I) make a single pull request? Or do I need to make two, and then comment in the second pull request that it won't work unless the first changeset has been merged on the other repository?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I can see of [GitHub pull request](https://web.archive.org/web/20110311075944/http://help.github.com/pull-requests/), this operation is linked to a single GitHub repository:

> By default, pull requests are assumed to be based on the parent-most repository’s integration branch.
>   In a great majority of cases, the defaults will be right; however, if any of this information is incorrect, press the `Change Commits` button.
>   The commit range selector will expand, allowing the base repository, base branch, and head branch to be customized.

[image]

Only one base repo can be entered.

So in your case, a note mentioning the dependency seems the relevant option here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and it is smart, especially for the repositories(like libraries) being shared across multiple projects!

In bigger companies this is a part of normal development process for over 10 years. The problem is that there are not so many services publicly available being able doing this. The only available tool I've found is [Reviewboard](https://www.reviewboard.org) that looks to be a copy of Amazon internal service for code review, so probably ex-amazonians will find this very familiar.

Comment: Gerrit does this too. But the UX is atrocious.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Review Board can do this either: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/reviewboard/o1iupZ9komY

Comment: As an ex-Amazonian I found this answer kind of hilarious because Amazon migrated from Reviewboard to their in-house solution somewhere in the 2015ish era.